# How to define margin (CSS) around an absolutely positioned, floating element?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

Before I explain...

**This is the HTML part:**

```
<div class="HeadingTabs">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="http://google.com" class="TabLink">Google</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="TitleTab">This is some very very long title. This is some very very long title. This is a very long title.</div>
</div>
```

**This is the CSS part:**

```
.HeadingTabs {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 2px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

.HeadingTabs ul {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 8px;
}

.HeadingTabs li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}

.TitleTab {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    line-height: 2.6;
    white-space: nowrap;

/* I haven't included the styling info like
borders and background to avoid unnecessary
distractions in code. */

}
```

Now... as you can see, the `ul` element is floating right and is absolutely positioned to the bottom-right of the parent div. This is what I meant, when I said 'an absolutely positioned, floating element.'

Dispite the giving it a margin, I am unable to prevent the title (`<div class="TitleTab">` element) from protruding into it. The image below should make it clear.

[image: Imgur]

What am I missing?

Points of note:

- I cannot modify the HTML. My only go is CSS.
- I want the title to wrap around the `ul` element. So, I can't use width.
- I am using `position: absolute;` because I want the `ul` element to stay at the bottom of the div right above the content div (just cut-off in the image).

*PS: I am not very proficient with CSS.*

Comment: Once you use `position: absolute`, the element will be taken out of the document flow. Ditch the absolute positioning and just use the float.

Comment: Not being able to change the HTML makes this difficult. If you know about how many characters the positioned element will be, you could leave room for it by appending non-breaking spaces to the title: `.TitleTab:after {content: "\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0\a0";}` (Won't work in IE7). You would also need to remove the `white-space: nowrap;`, as Johnny Craig stated.

Comment: @DavidKolar Hmm... changing the HTML seems to be the only option I've got. Thanks for chipping in with your thoughts.

Comment: The `.TitleTab:after` pseudo class should work with the existing HTML, _if_ you have and idea of the needed width.

Comment: @DavidKolar I think so. I am testing various things right this moment. I will have my own answer here if I cook up something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `absolute:position` function is designed to be protruded into.

you should try floating the elements instead without the absolute:position

```
.HeadingTabs ul {
    margin:10px;
   float: right;
}


 .TitleTab {
     float:left;
     margin: 0;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 5px 10px;
     line-height: 2.6;
     white-space: nowrap; // you need to remove no wrap, so it wraps instead of cuts off
 }
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I have added some points that should make it more clear.

Comment: if the `.HeadingTab` is the same height as the `ul` it should stay at the bottom like you want. unfortunately css does not have a `float:bottom right;`.. if the heading and list cannot have the same height because it changes height depending on the length of the text, i am unable to think of a way to keep the list at the bottom without modifying the html and using a table.. if they can be the same height, just set the heights in the css `height: 40px;`

Comment: you could also use javascript (if its possible) to set the max number of characters in the `.TitleTab` so it looks like: `This is a very long title, this is a...`

Comment: I will try to find a way in. If I can't I will choose between JS or a HTML table like youu suggested. And thanks for you suggestions.